# Android Studio: auto-import keymap

Tags: android, android-studio

I cleaned up my keymap settings in Android Studio 1.3 and I lost the ability to press "alt-enter" to select the correct class from multiple possibilities. For example, when I add a reference to "Fragment" I see the tool-tip and I need to select "android.support.v4.app.Fragment" but the 'alt-enter' keymap has been (mistakenly) removed. I want to restore it but I can't find the correct command.

[image]

QUESTION: What is the keymap entry (under File > Settings > Keymap) that needs to be set so I can select the correct class to import?

Comment: Keymap entry is called *"Show Intention Actions"*

Comment: "Show Intention Actions" did the trick. If you create an answer I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do like this to resolve your problem:-

- Goto android studio setting
- in search bar type -> " auto "
- Select "Auto Import"
- Check other two check box
  1--> Optimize import on fly 
  2--> add unambiguous imports on fly

I hope its help you

Comment: This works only for *unambiguous* imports -- my situation has multiple possible imports and I need to choose the correct one. "Show Intention Actions" (see above) is the answer.